# NDIS driver - how?

Tags: sdk, driver, wdk, ndis

I have read nearly all of the material on Microsoft's MSDN site, used Google (for the limited information that is out there) and also looked at the answers on here but I'm still confused on how to develop a NDIS driver.

My aim is to create a ndis driver so I can capture the network packets and decide whether I want to drop them (possibly inject as well) or allow them to pass.

From my research it would seem that I need to create an intermediate NIDS driver and after installing WDK (I'm using Visual Studio 2015 enterprise) I don't know where to begin (do I need to start with a KMDF project?).

Also, when I did load a KMDF driver project nearly all of the header files are getting highlighted by Intellisense as having errors (expected an identifier, NTSTATUS is underefined)?

Can anyone give some assistance on how to start please?

I have recently created a packet sniffer using the WinPcap library (and also used it to send packets) but there was a lot of information out there that helped me. Unfortunately, with NDIS it doesn't seem to be the same.

I can't seem to find the samples either

Comment: Start by looking at WDK samples, I believe you'll find there a close match to what you need: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/mt348991(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: Hi, thank you for that. I have installed the samples on my machine and opened up the one I want to look at further (ndisprot60) but I'm not sure WDK 10. and Visual studio 2015 are set up correctly as there a lot of Intellisense errors and #include headers not being recognized.

Comment: I'm trying to see if setting up a path to the WDK file is going to work

Answer (score 0):

Okay, so a simple clean install of Visual Studio 2015 and WDK 10 is all that is needed to set up the environment for creating a driver.....

But then comes the deployment part